# How to open browser windows one by one with Jmeter selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I was using jmeter with jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler plugin on Chrome driver.
When I set thread count to 100 it will open 100 browsers.
Is there any way to open the browser 1 after another?

Below is the code:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get('https://www.XXXX.com/dp/B087X9X2JZ')
java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000);
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('ebooksSitbLogo')); //saves search field into searchField
searchField.click();
java.lang.Thread.sleep(10000);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

- First of all you can get the best recommendations for this in 'jmeter.log'.

**Follow the given steps:**

> solution for Firefox browser

- Add given line in system.properties file (located in the /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

  webdriver.firefox.bin=/path/to/your/firefox.exe
- locate all duplicate http* libraries like httpcore*.jar httpmime.jar etc. and remove the ones with lesser version
- restart JMeter to pick the property and the changes up
- You can also refer this docs :https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered